# Why is Envoy is not queuing requests?

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm trying to configure envoy to queue requests to an upstream grpc service based on the circuit breaker configuration.

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/circuit_breaker.proto

My configuration looks like this

```
  clusters:
- name: grpc
  per_connection_buffer_limit_bytes: 10000000
  circuit_breakers:
    thresholds:
      - priority: DEFAULT
        max_connections: 1024
        max_pending_requests: 1024
        max_requests: 20
```

What I'm seeing is envoy responding with a 503 instead of queuing the request when the max_requests value is reached.  Using vegeta to send 10/second only 50% succeed.  Expecting all 50 requests to succeed.

```
echo "POST http://host.docker.internal:8888" | vegeta attack -body payload.json -rate 10 -duration=5s | tee results.bin | vegeta report
Requests      [total, rate, throughput]         50, 10.20, 3.62
Duration      [total, attack, wait]             7.467s, 4.901s, 2.566s
Latencies     [min, mean, 50, 90, 95, 99, max]  3.802ms, 2.192s, 2.568s, 5.061s, 5.463s, 5.684s, 5.684s
Bytes In      [total, mean]                     13294692, 265893.84
Bytes Out     [total, mean]                     16057050, 321141.00
Success       [ratio]                           54.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]                      200:27  503:23  
Error Set:
503 Service Unavailable
```

Comment: same situation here. Did you find out how envoy queues requests?

Comment: @Yoh haven't found out why, maybe grpc/http2 protocol works different.

Comment: the following might work. 

        max_connections: 10
        max_pending_requests: 1024
        max_requests: 1024

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/21121